# TS/JS : conditional async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have a trading algorithm placing orders depending on prices it receives from a stream of data.
When in production, we receive prices from a WS socket, so it is naturally asynchronous.

Though, we wanted to test our algorithm with pre-loaded prices sent to the algorithm synchronisly. The problem is that, as the algorithm is fully asynchronous in production, all function are marked async and have await calls in them. Though, in the "test" mode, all that async functions actually return `Promise.resolve(whatever)` immediately because everything is fake (prices are fake, placing order is fake etc.) and we don't wait for anything from the Internet.

The problem is that, as all these functions are asynchronous, despite they return immediately a `promise.resolve(whatever)`, they are much slower that if they returned `whatever` directly.

My question is : is it possible to make "asyncOrNot" functions in JS/TS that would be called with "awaitOrNot" ? If not, what approach can be thought of in this situation to get rid of all the async overhead time, to make the "fake" environment faster ? I'd like to avoid to maintain 2 different algorithms (one production async one and another sync one for test purposes)

Just a little piece of code to understand what I'd like :

```
abstract class PriceStream {
    onPriceCallback: (price: number) => PromiseOrNot<void>
    abstract startStreaming(): void
}

class RealAsyncPriceStream extends PriceStream { 
    startStreaming() {
        // this is not real WebSocket functions but it's just for you to understand
        // that prices are arriving and sent asynchronously to the callback here
        webSocket.onMessage((message) => {
            const price = ... // do formatting of message to a price
            this.onPriceCallback(price)
        })
        webSocket.start() 
    }
}

class FakeSyncPriceStream extends PriceStream {
    startStreaming() {
        const prices = [0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10]
        for (price of prices) {
            this.onPriceCallback(price)
        }
    }
}


class Algo {
    constructor(priceSteam: PriceStream) {
        priceStream.onPriceCallback = this.onPrice.bind(this)
    }
    run() {
        priceStream.startStreaming()
    }
    
    asyncOrNot onPrice(): PromiseOrNot<void> {
        // perform business operations that are : 
        // - all asynchronous in production (placing and cancelling order awaits for the broker response)
        // - all synchronous in fake environment : placing and cancelling orders only locally in memory : all async function return immediately Promise.resolve(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: *they are way slower* They shouldn't be - a `Promise.resolve` will resolve essentially immediately and should be fine to use

Comment: Well we have tons of prices (1 year at 20 prices per second), and after doing some test with async VS sync code it looks like having sync code speeds up the whole test drastically

Comment: @JeremLachkar What are you testing that needs 630 million values? Is this a performance test?

Comment: just backtesting our trading strategy :)

Comment: I think it could be done. You roll your own Promise impl and tell TS to transpile `await` against your fake Promise API, which under the hood skips all async overhead.

Comment: You might want to try generator functions and `yield` instead of `await`, running them with a "coroutine runner" like back in the old ES6 (pre-ES8) days :-) Then you can run them synchronously in tests.

Comment: @hackape looks great but how do you tell TS what to do when using "await" ?

Comment: @Bergi not a big fan of these new features but I'll definitely check this out:)

Comment: @JeremLachkar generator functions are far older than `async`/`await` syntax :-)

Comment: @JeremLachkar `await` is transpiled to promise and generator based impl by TS. Just try in the playground (target ES5) to see what I mean. At the end of day, it’s still promise.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea. Like I said in comment, it's possible with a custom promise impl that shadows the native impl. You need to apply it as polyfill to override `globalThis.Promise`.

With TS compile target set to `ES2016` and lesser, compiled JS code will not using `async/await` language feature. Instead it uses generator and Promise, which will put your custom impl to work.

Below is my impl. It automatically adapts to sync and async behavior, depending on whether you synchronously call the `resolve/reject` callback when instantiating Promise. Not production ready because interface is not aligned to spec. But enough to demonstrate the idea.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgUwIYBsAKAnEBbAlhBGAXhgHMUQAjVAFQAt8A6THfBAKGBSQghgGUAnmGAs8BGAG92MGNCRRcwGBgQQQKAG4IAFJtQBXBAEopM2SoRQDGMDDAIA7gOGis43TtXqtJ4gD5LH209QxNjcwBfdnNQSCgMA2AoEAwdYFQUamAAa1NpCxgoBghGeWs+EgByAAcEMAATXDBSKvNZYqZvDW1iGFCUI1MiQILCopKyqAUDSpgq7t8GtvGJpn1BwhINo3aLTtLEsB0IwujCg8ZVACsEZL6BoYCzVcvy2b6FhFvkhGW9jqTHZbGDAgFrQ4GY6nCzRPaXDIoLJIXJzADaAF0YhcMIIXuNEcjcjpLottAAaCFXb53KAw2SRGAAM2amTxY0KuCZ-Te0wqxCI1TqjWarXy4NkqmstnsTngyHQ7jYOi8ah6CEpN1pw1GEv2k0J2RypRqszoOjRZI1lh+UAx9PGkQdDL25xgcMB9R04AAYgYUCykX8HgAPHUwEOU8CIW3Bkg6MPPRMcyzSuwOZxCERiZVeCCa67hlOyCCOXBQYB0HmTd4QcWrWQZCS1epNFpVABcetklFUSByeqbhC+wT+ne7Kgg3rAfoDuCDDRJQLCxmd417yAHDZgQ-mWt+yy728l12nMdpfyX6xXa8KG-74LdDJhHpUUJO+Mb4GgO8yRrmCJ-iixrwgaQGon0mJ7EyqT9CgVgwGivr+oG8ENFGYDngeGIwCA3KGsBdafhYXLVkwtYCtUVrLPWDbIXOC5XqUwJroyCAoBIpFMVMMyVIKe40geVS0as0aCVAl6XCxj6ulE7BwuQVC0JMOYSCQWZuKwBAxDwrjMlCyS4OAMDYEgzQfim8GwMCfRII4ZmwKpCDUqOOgACwAEwOnEPjORQpCPCY8kxFZuEGLAJCmeZEQ+RofkgAFVQgOFVRRuFxhAA)

```js
const RealPromise = globalThis.Promise
class SyncPromise {
  static resolve(value) {
    return new SyncPromise((resolve) => resolve(value))
  }

  constructor(callback) {
    this.status = 'pending'
    this.resolve = (value) => {
      this.status = 'resolved'
      this.value = value
      this.run()
    }
    this.reject = (value) => {
      this.status = 'rejected'
      this.value = value
      this.run()
    }

    this.callbacks = []

    try {
      callback(this.resolve, this.reject)
    } finally {
      if (this.status === 'pending') {
        return new RealPromise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.callbacks.push([resolve, reject])
        })
      }
    }
  }

  then(onFulfilled = (x) => x, onRejected = (x) => x) {
    return new SyncPromise((rs, rj) => {
      switch (this.status) {
        case 'pending':
          break
        case 'resolved':
          rs(onFulfilled(this.value))
          break
        case 'rejected':
          rj(onRejected(this.value))
          break
      }
    })
  }

  run() {
    const callbacks = this.callbacks
    this.callbacks = []
    for (let [onFulfilled, onRejected] of callbacks) {
      if (this.status === 'resolved') {
        onFulfilled(this.value)
      } else if (this.status === 'rejected') {
        onRejected(this.value)
      }
    }
  }
}

globalThis.Promise = SyncPromise

async function main() {
    let value = await Promise.resolve(42)
    console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to overwrite the `__awaiter`, not `Promise` - much simpler, less error-prone than `SyncPromise`. Then make the mock functions return values synchronously instead of returning promises, and make the awaiter not use `Promise.resolve` but a synchronous loop

Comment: Btw since OP is looking for speed, they should set the target to ES2015 or ES2016 so that the code transpiles to native generators - the ES5 generator polyfill like in the playground you linked is horribly slow in comparison

Comment: Good point about using native generator. I was focused on promise and completely ignored that part.

Comment: But I fail to follow the idea about overwriting awaiter instead of promise. I mean, how can it be done without hacking promise impl?

Comment: You can trivially [assign to `__awaiter`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/PrCGHdQSwFwUwE4AIC8SDGB7AdgZ0wDZwB0BmA5gNwBQ1ouAntukgGYCuzMUOSAttGwAKAJRIA3tSTSkRGEgBuoAuziokEaPIAsAJikyseQiTLkhSlXBHUAvrTlJM7eWgFRhNo-iKkKQgHJnGACAGicXESA), or also create a global variable before the transpiled module is executed.

Comment: @Bergi You missed my point. I know I can overwrite `__awaiter` with some custom impl. My point is, it's simply impossible to turn async code into sync code solely by overwriting `__awaiter`. Something must be done to `Promise`.

Comment: I was suggesting that the fake/mock apis the OP is calling from their `onPrice` algorithm don't return promises at all (neither real ones nor `SyncPromise`s) but just plain values, and that the `__awaiter` asserts this and then runs the generator synchronously.

Comment: Now I get your point. Yes, that’s even better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll give it a try and come back to you with some performance comparison:)

Comment: Sure thing. But I'd stress that you still need to improve on my impl for it to work with real code. Multiple things are missing, e.g. I didn't handle unwrapping promise. `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(42)).then(val => console.log(val))` will give you `Promise<42>` where as it should be `42`.